# MySQL outer-join with joined-table having dependencies to more than one table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have 3 tables A, B and T

T holds a foreign key to table A and B respectively.

Now I would like to get all rows of (A,B,T) even if T is empty.

```
SELECT * from

A
LEFT OUTER JOIN T t1 ON t1.A_ID = A.id,
B
LEFT OUTER JOIN T t2 ON t2.B_ID = B.id

WHERE A.B_ID = B.ID
```

Now the problem is that I get too many rows so I add the following:

```
AND t1.id = t2.id
```

But now I get no rows at all which I tried to avoid in the first place via including the LEFT OUTER JOIN.

EDIT: Apart from any sample-data or table-layout my question is merely if a table T with foreign-key-dependencies to more than ONE table in this case A + B needs 2 left-outer-joins as given above or maybe there is another way?

Simply refering to table A in the second left-join like some users suggested cannot work as it is out-of-scope, also explained 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820724/mysql-5-left-join-unknown-column)
So it works if you surround both tables with parens:

```
SELECT * from (A, B)
LEFT OUTER JOIN T t ON t.A_ID = A.id and t.B_ID = B.id
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but what's the purpose of A.B_ID = B.ID? Could you perhaps post table definitions and sample data?

Comment: You may want to try something like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql

Comment: For your own sanity (and to an extent, ours) please don't mix `,` and `JOIN` notation.  Try using one, preferably `JOIN`.  Also, you can () parts of your query, such as `(A LEFT JOIN T ON ???) INNER JOIN (B LEFT JOIN T ON ???) ON ???`

Comment: How can we use "on A.B_ID = B.ID" if this both tables don't have any relation? You given "T holds a foreign key to table A and B".

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info - the table structure and your expected output. Its not clear from the question if A and B are related. If not, do you want a cartesian product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:
If A and B no any relation:

```
SELECT * FROM
(A, B)
LEFT OUTER JOIN T ON T.A_ID = A.id
AND T.B_ID = B.id
```

And if A and B have relation add this line at last:

```
WHERE A.B_ID = B.ID
```

Comment: I don't think this can work as A.id is "unknown" in the outer join. You are stating table-B AFTER table-A

Comment: i have tested it. it works. if your table structure is as you given.

Comment: Your solution works if I surround A, B with parens => (A, B). Maybe this is a must in MySQL

Comment: Oh...Sorry..Thanks. I have changed my solution. Brackets should be there.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
select *
from A
join B on A.B_ID = B.ID
left join T on T.A_ID = a.id and T.B_ID = b.id
```

.. assuming I've understood your question correctly, and you intend a regular, inner join between A and B

Comment: How can we use "on A.B_ID = B.ID" if this both tables don't have any relation? "T holds a foreign key to table A and B".

Comment: The `WHERE` clause in the original question implies a relation between A and B

Comment: +1, although I'm somewhat unsure as to whether the second `ON` clause should connect the two comparisons with `AND` or with `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood right, then maybe this will work for you?

```
SELECT * from
A
LEFT OUTER JOIN T t1 ON t1.A_ID = A.id,
B
LEFT OUTER JOIN T t2 ON (t2.B_ID = B.id AND t1.id = t2.id)

WHERE A.B_ID = B.ID
```

Comment: This is the problem, I am trying to solve: t1.id is unknown in the second LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: OOps, Sorry, didn't notice the comma... Maybe then SELECT * from A
LEFT OUTER JOIN T t1 ON t1.A_ID = A.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON (t1.B_ID = B.id AND A.B_ID = B.ID)
will help

Comment: but still, what relation is between **A** AND **B**?